# Tethering a "reversed tethered" data from a pc?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, reverse-tether

I have a Samsung Galaxy S 4G mini (GT-I8190) and I know I have the *hotspot* feature built-in which transforms my phone into a modem. I have used it plenty of times to tether my phone to other devices (tablet, laptop, etc).

I have discovered recently that it is possible to do a *Reverse Tethering* and plug the phone to the computer via the USB and get data running on the phone from the PC.

Now, I am interested to combine the two - in order to transform my phone into a real *router*. I tried to enable the hotspot while getting data from the PC. The phone has access to the internet. And my tablet was able to join the hotspot Wi-Fi network - but it has no network access.

Can anyone shed some light on:

1. How *USB-tunneling* works as far as transmitting the data from the
   PC? All I know is that it forwards data from a certain port on the
   PC. I tried to find an "open code source" for the USB Tunneling app but could not. I wanted to have a look on how they manage the data.
2. How does the built-in *hotspot* feature functions? Does it only forwards the Mobile Data to the Wi-Fi? Can anyone share/direct me where to find an open code source for a  tethering app? (the built-in hotspot works perfectly - but all downloaded tethering apps fail to run on my I8190).
3. I tried to find a tutorial, app, or anything that can explain on how to Wi-Fi tether a Reversed Tethered data without great success. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you solve this problem yet?

Comment: No I didn't. But if you have an unlocked phone and can program it should be potentially possible - in concept at least. I just gave up on the idea. If i will have time this weekend I might try to program something.

Comment: Reversed tetheted via Wi-Fi? Do you want to make your device a Wi-Fi repeater of some sort?

Comment: Yes, that was the general idea back in 2013. As mobile tethering packages are limited, I wanted to turn off the data package on my phone, and plug my phone to the PC - and use the PC's internet as the phone's data tethering source. The issue was that the phone gets the data and is able to use - but is not able to tether it out. So I would not call the phone being used as a "repeater" - more like the PC's antenna, or wifi-router.